# How can I prevent C# from redrawing a <div> I used jQuery to show

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Scenario:  I have a modal-style div that will be shown when the user clicks a button.  At the time the div is shown, I need to get some data from the back-end to fill in some fields.  Additionally, I'd like to use the jQuery method I use for all my modal windows (fades in the modal div, displays a background div as well as enabling the use of ESC key or "click offs" to close the modal).

It looks something like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sc" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updForm" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <h4>Testing jQuery calls combined with code behind actions</h4>
        <div class="pad-content">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkShowIt" runat="server" OnClick="lnkShowIt_Click" Text="Load Form" OnClientClick="showForm()" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="box-modal" style="width:500px;display:none;z-index:1001">
            <div class="header">Edit Estimate <a href="javascript: disablePopup()" class="button">X</a></div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="window">
                    <h5>Test Form</h5>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxTime" runat="server" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxText" runat="server" Width="150px" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkValidate" runat="server" CssClass="link-button-blue" Text="Validate" OnClick="lnkValidate_Click" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
            </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

So ... lnkShowIt calls both the jQuery (which will show pnlPopup) as well as the C# (which will populate tbxTime).

jQuery method actually just calls another method from a common js library I have that does the modal window stuff - I don't think that actual code is the problem but here is the simple function used for this page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function showForm() {
        loadPopup('#pnlPopup');
    }

</script>
```

Code behind methods look like this:
        protected void lnkShowIt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbxTime.Text = System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
        }

```
    protected void lnkValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbxTime.Text == tbxText.Text)
        {
            Response.Redirect("DynamicBoxesWithJQuery.aspx?mode=success");
        }
        else
        {
            tbxText.Style["border"] = "1px solid red";
        }
    }
```

I'm able to generate some level of success by doing the following but it seems like just a major hack and I have to assume there's a better approach:

```
protected void lnkShowIt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbxTime.Text = System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "OpenEditor", "<script type='text/javascript'>loadPopup('#pnlPopup');</script>", false);
    }

    protected void lnkValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbxTime.Text == tbxText.Text)
        {
            Response.Redirect("DynamicBoxesWithJQuery.aspx?mode=success");
        }
        else
        {
            tbxText.Style["border"] = "1px solid red";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "OpenEditor", "<script type='text/javascript'>loadPopup('#pnlPopup');</script>", false);
        }
    }
```

It seems like it should be easier than this, but the way the UpdatePanel keeps redrawing (and thus resetting the display:none on pnlPopup) is really causing me fits.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank heavens we have someone who can properly format their code on this site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I just found: putting the LinkButton in its own UpdatePanel and then the form in its own UpdatePanel and making sure the div that is the actual popup box is not in an UpdatePanel at all.

```
<h4>Testing jQuery calls combined with code behind actions</h4>
<div class="pad-content">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updLink" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkShowIt" runat="server" OnClick="lnkShowIt_Click" Text="Load Form" OnClientClick="showForm()" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="box-modal" style="width:500px;display:none;z-index:1001">
        <div class="header">Edit Estimate <a href="javascript: disablePopup()" class="button">X</a></div>
        <div class="content">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updForm" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="window"style="min-width:500px;">
                    <h5>Here is a Test Form</h5>
                    <label>Time:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxTime" runat="server" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblText" AssociatedControlID="tbxText" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">Text:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxText" runat="server" Width="150px" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkValidate" runat="server" CssClass="link-button-blue" Text="Validate" OnClick="lnkValidate_Click" />
                </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Seems to do the trick without any Script Registers from the codebehind